# construct object in realtime with IIFE as method

Tags: javascript, object, iife

when i want that the property get year to print, i cant acces to the variable
I have this obj:

```
let human = {
  birdYear: 1,
  getAge: (function (birdYear) {
    return 2021 - this.birdYear
  })()
};
```

when print human get this:

```
Cannot read property 'birdYear' of birdYear
```

and i want get this:

```
{
  birdYear: 1
  getAge: 2020
}
```

some cane help me? I thy with using:

- 'this.'
- without 'this.birdYear'
- (fn(birdYear){...birdYear})()
- (fn(birdYear){...birdYear})(this.birdYear)

and nothing

THANKS

// ADD

i found this way

```
let human = {
  birdYear: 1,
  get getAge() {
    return new Date().getFullYear() - this.birdYear
  }
};
```

Works!
I only need to understand why not I use IIFE as methods...

Comment: `this` refers to your function, not to the object it belongs, because the object is an object literal, not a class instance.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you want to create a class that you can instantiate and serialize with a built-in accessor (i.e. `get`) method?

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(age) {
    this.age = age;
  }
  get birthYear() {
    return new Date().getUTCFullYear() - this.age;
  }
  serialize() {
    return { age: this.age, birthYear: this.birthYear };
  }
}

let bird = new Animal(1);

console.log(bird.serialize());
```